# SMD Bread board and electrical simulation software

Tags: electrical-engineering

I am designing a DC-DC boost converter using an SMD LM2623 and an inductor which is also SMD of 4.7 μH. I want to first build a prototype but I can't use an ordinary breadboard. Could someone please advise me whether there is a way I can mount SMD components for testing?

Secondly, I have failed to get an electronic simulator having LM2623, does someone know any simulator which can help me do my circuit analysis?

Comment: The second question is a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site. The first part seems fine, though.

Comment: What is the intended $V_{in}$ and  $V_{out}$?

Comment: Google "surface mount breadboard adapter."

Answer (score 2):

Most simplest and cost effective method is the purchase a LM2623 Evaluation Board board. The Evaluation board looks something like the following.

[image: LM2623 Evaluation Board image]

If you contact your Texas Instrument Sales representative you can almost get the board free or for a very nominal price.

The alternate option is to look for similar DC-DC converter break out boards. They might not have a exact one-one mapping but might do a job for simple prototyping experiment. Below is an alternate from Pololu [Adjustable 4-12V Step-Up Voltage Regulator U3V50ALV](https://www.pololu.com/product/2570)

[image: Adjustable 4-12V Step-Up Voltage Regulator]

I have attach a few references that you might want research further.

Another option is to use surface mount to thru hole converters. Below is an example. Below is an example of one such from Jameco. Issue is at the end your cost might be the same as purchasing a EVM of Texas Instrument.

[image: Protoboard Soic To Dip 6 Board 2-SOT 23 2-SOT 323 353 2-SC70]

There are many options. All you have to do is to make the necessary compromise as pertaining to your project.

**References:**

- [Pololu Adjustable 9-30V Step-Up Voltage Regulator U3V50AHV](https://www.pololu.com/product/2571)
- [Regulators and Power Supplies - Step-Up Voltage Regulators](https://www.pololu.com/category/132/step-up-voltage-regulators)
- [General Purpose, Gated Oscillator Based, DC DC Boost Converter - LM2623EV](http://www.ti.com/tool/lm2623ev)
- [Electronic Prototyping Adapters](http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/StoreCatalogDrillDownView?langId=-1&storeId=10001&catalogId=10001&categoryName=cat_6520&subCategoryName=Electronic%20Design%20%2F%20Prototyping%20Systems%20%2F%20Prototype%20Adapters&category=652030)
- [Power Converter Boosters](https://www.adafruit.com/categories/570)